# Overlay contour plot over the map

Tags: python, matplotlib, plotly, contour, geopandas

I'm trying to plot a contour plot over a map

it's kind of look like this

[image]

What i have now is,

```
    import matplotlib
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import geopandas as gpd
    import plotly.express as px
    import pandas as pd

    world_map = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres'))

    axis = world[world.continent == 'Asia'].plot(color='white', edgecolor='black')
    fig = matplotlib.pyplot.gcf()
    fig.set_size_inches(14,10)
```

it's output look like this
[image]

I have a contour plot

```
    import plotly.graph_objects as go
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    from scipy.interpolate import griddata

    df = pd.read_csv('./temperature_2d.csv')
    x = np.array(df.lon)
    y = np.array(df.lat)
    z = np.array(df.value)
    xi = np.linspace(x.min(), x.max(), 100)
    yi = np.linspace(y.min(), y.max(), 100)

    X,Y = np.meshgrid(xi,yi)
    Z = griddata((x,y),z,(X,Y), method='cubic')

    fig = go.Figure(data =
    go.Contour(
    z=Z,
    x=xi,
    y=yi,
    colorscale = 'Hot',
    contours_coloring='heatmap'
    ))
    fig.show()
```

The data file is [temperature_2d.csv](https://drive.google.com/file/d/17q0yxh56PYqN5a4XnCe7TambutVloDQM/view) 
it's output plot is,

[image]

What i am trying to do is overlay the contour plot over the the locations that i have in the [temperature_2d.csv](https://drive.google.com/file/d/17q0yxh56PYqN5a4XnCe7TambutVloDQM/view) on the map, but i cannot find a way to do that.I don't know the way i doing it correct or not.

If anyone can explian how to do this correctly it will be really helpfull.

Comment: I've never worked with those specific packages, but in matplotlib you would adjust the transparency. You know how colors on the computer are specified by RGB (red green blue)? Well there's a RGBA with an extra parameter *alpha* for transparency, exactly for the purpose of overlaying images. Matplotlib functions have a `alpha` parameter that works the same way for the whole plot e.g. `plt.plot(x,y, alpha = 0.5)`. You can also name specific RGBA colors with a tuple, so fully transparent white background color would be `color=(1,1,1,1)`.

Comment: take a look at this question I answered https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69443849/adding-geojson-contours-as-layers-on-plotly-density-mapbox/69447513#69447513

Comment: @RobRaymond Thanks that's very helpful, is there qny option to add reference axis in plotly