# How can I limit the shape of a contour map and make it non-rectangular in Plotly

Tags: plotly, plotly-dash, plotly-python

I have a contour map representing pressure on which I added a line graph that represent the shape of the reservoir as shown below.

[image]

How can I make the contour map to be only within the shape and to ignore outside shape?

Comment: Please provide a minimal viable code example so we can follow your steps so far. Thank you!

Comment: it's not clear what you are trying to achieve. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69443849/adding-geojson-contours-as-layers-on-plotly-density-mapbox/69447513#69447513 demonstrates using **density_mapbox**